# i am unable findthe app_package and app_activity in MobileCompatibityType while coding in eclipse for appium.This is for testing the native app

Tags: android, eclipse, appium

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class LaunchAppium {

    AndroidDriver driver;
      // driver = new AndroidDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", test);

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities test=new DesiredCapabilities();
        test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Androidemulator");
        test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "Ebutor 15_dec_2016.apk");
        //test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType., value);
        driver = new AndroidDr`enter code here`iver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), test);

    }
```

In the above pice of code i could not find the APP_PACKAGE and APP_ACTIVITY for the mobilecapabilitytpe instance which is essential for the android settings.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

From 4.0, this is moved to specific to android package:

```
public interface AndroidMobileCapabilityType extends CapabilityType {
/**
 * Activity name for the Android activity you want to launch from your package.
 * This often needs to be preceded by a . (e.g., .MainActivity instead of MainActivity).
 */
  String APP_ACTIVITY = "appActivity";

  /**
   * Java package of the Android app you want to run.
 */
```

String APP_PACKAGE = "appPackage";

```
 /**
    * Activity name for the Android activity you want to wait for.
    */
   String APP_WAIT_ACTIVITY = "appWaitActivity";
```

}

So you have to use

```
AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY
```

Please check the above it should work or you can see the see @ [link](http://qahumor.blogspot.in/2015/06/appium-sample-demo-program-of-android.html)

Comment: No i am ending up with errors if i am running the above function.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Comment: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
 at com.appium.android.LaunchAppium.setup(LaunchAppium.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: can you paste the entire code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can u please have a look.It is throwing error if i run the above piece of code

Comment: Do we need to configure selenium 2.45 jars into the ecclipse ide

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.appium.android;



import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class LaunchAppium {

    static AndroidDriver driver;
      // driver = new AndroidDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", test);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities test=new DesiredCapabilities();
        //test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator");
        //test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator.MainActivity");
        test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator");
        test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2.2");
        test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "android");
        //test.setCapability("appPackage",
                "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator");
           //test.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");
            //driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                    test);

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), test);


    }
    public interface AndroidMobileCapabilityType extends CapabilityType {
          String APP_ACTIVITY = "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator.MainActivity";
          String APP_PACKAGE = "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator";


    }

    @Test
    public void atest() throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver two=(WebDriver) driver.findElement(By.linkText("2"));
        ((WebElement) two).click();
        WebDriver plus= (WebDriver) driver.findElement(By.linkText("+"));
        ((WebElement) plus).click();
        WebDriver five= (WebDriver) driver.findElement(By.linkText("5"));
        ((WebElement) five).click();
        WebDriver equal= (WebDriver) driver.findElement(By.linkText("="));
        ((WebElement) equal).click();




    }

}
```

Comment: you have to use  AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY   , for example test.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.veronicaapps.veronica.simplecalculator.MainActivity");